# Batch copy folder-name to clipboard?

Tags: batch-file, directory, rename

Is it possible to copy the first sub-folder-**name** in a main-folder to clipboard and set this sub-folder-name for a .jpg ?

---

**Example:**

---

- **C:\Users\Admin\main-folder**

  - sub-Folder-name1
  - subFolder-name2
  - subFolder-name3

---

I want that everytime the batch run only the name of the first sub-folder get copied (**sub-Folder1**) and set this name for a .jpg in another folder with an additional name.

---

**Example Output:**

---

sub-Folder-name1 `+` _GranCanaria `+`.jpg

---

the file will then be called at the end `sub-Folder-name1_GranCanaria.jpg`

Comment: May be helpful: http://superuser.com/questions/231023/windows-script-to-copy-some-text-to-the-clipboard

Comment: Thank you, was helpful to copy to clipboard.
`echo|set /p=%%~nxF|clip`

Now I have to try to rename my .jpg files with the copied folder name.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to set and retrieve the contents of the clipboard when you could just set and reference a variable?  Why not just `ren "path\to\file.jpg" "%~nxF_GranCanaria.jpg"`?

Comment: Later I will use this for other files. So the batch compress with winrar and rendom-names .. `subfolder1 to another newfolder and delete subfolder1 after compress is ready` and create a .sfv file. Now I want that the .sfv file get the name of the original folder (`subfolder1`). Because of this I want to do it with the clipboard.

Comment: @ rojo
@Gary
Ok, solved it the way "rojo" says. I clone subfolder1 (without files inside) before winrar compress the files inside and delete subfolder1. So that I can later set in the script `set "FolderName=%%~nxF"` and `ren "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\newfolder\!_RndAlphaNum!.sfv" "%%~nxF".sfv"` and after renaming the script delete the empty subfolder1 `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (`"dir "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\newfolder\" /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"`